# How to add cookies with "setVideoHeaders" method of VideoView of Vitamio for Android?

Tags: android, cookies, http-headers, android-videoview, vitamio

I edited **VideoViewDemo.java** (the Android Vitamio demo provided by official website) for the purpose of **adding cookies** into the request headers that produced by Vitamio.
(The headers were sent automatically while using the method "setVideoPath".)

Original VideoViewDemo.java:

```
...
} else {
        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
...
```

Edited VideoViewDemo.java:

```
...
} else {

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Cookie", "test=abc; test2=def");
        mVideoView.setVideoHeaders(headers);

        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
...
```

Then I used **Wireshark** to check the packets.

The result I "expected":

[image: expected result]

The result I obtained:

[image: actual result]

It showed that the cookies I tried to add weren't contained in the request headers that produced by Vitamio.
Is there anything wrong in my code? 
Or is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Device: HTC J Z321e
Android version: 4.1.1
Vitamio version: 4.2.0 *(2013-12-31)*
IDE: Eclipse on Windows 7 32 Bit
Image url: [http://imgur.com/dY7qajG&lHoxxwo#0](https://imgur.com/dY7qajG&lHoxxwo#0)

Comment: same question . please contact me if you hava any solution,thank

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. Headers are in AVOption style, so shuold be used in following way:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("headers", "Cookie:"+stringCookie+"\r\n"+"User-agent:Mozilla\r\n");
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url), headers);
```

Comment: Note: Only valid when supporting API 21+. Earlier APIs do not have a headers parameter in the setVideoURI.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("Cookie", "a=" + cokkievalue);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url), headers);
```

This works perfect